# Changing Orientation and Pressing Back Button is giving Blank Screen in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

**Problem :-** Changing Orientation and Pressing Back Button is giving Blank Screen in Android Fragment.

Could any one explain,How to store Fragment history when Changing screen Orientation

For Example ,

--> Consider I am having three fragment,Frag1 --> Frag2 --> Frag3,

--> Currently I am in seeing Frag3,and If I press backbutton from Frag3 ,

--> I have to see fragments in this order Frag3 --> Frag2 --> Frag1,

--> But If I change orientation,I am getting Blank Screen for Frag2 and Frag3

Comment: are you adding the fragments to backstack?

Comment: Yes,But still getting Blank Screen.Could you post any example for this,[one more thing,I am using master-slave fragment concept]

Comment: Show some code ? So that we can help

Comment: Are they permanently blank after orientation change, or only during transition animation when you press back button?